# Proxy Pass react app in nginx for domain path

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I create react app for admin page and use nginx to serve reactjs file through port 3000.
If I set only home, it works well.

```
location /{
    proxy_pass http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

If I set like below it does work with http://localhost/admin but js file not be loaded.

```
location ^~ /admin {
    proxy_pass http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

[image]
Can you tell me why and which solution for this?

Comment: Are nginx and the nodejs app running on the same server?

Comment: Hi @IvanShatsky yes. It is running on same server. I want to deploy `react admin` to /admin folder and `react home` to home directory '/'

Comment: You should change all your assets URIs to `/admin/static/...` (as well as routes). [Here](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/) you can find some examples on how it can be done.